# mouseleave event for document, with consideration for Chrome bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I need to safely detect when the mouse leaves the window. I have jQuery included, so normally this would be fine:

```
$(document).on("mouseleave", function(event) {
  doSomething();
});
```

However, there is a [*major bug*](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798535) in Chrome currently where this `mouseleave` function fires randomly when clicking in the element.

Normally, there's an easy work around for this:

```
$("#some-id").on("mouseleave", function(event) {
  var e        = event.originalEvent;
  if (!e.relatedTarget || !e.toElement) {
    // BUG in Chrome
    return;
  }
  doSomething();
}
```

**However**, this doesn't work for `document`, or for any element when the mouse leaves the window, since in this case, `e.relatedTarget` and `e.toElement` are null *exactly like when the bug occurs*. So I'm trying to come up with something that will be able to safely determine when Chrome is acting up, and when the mouseleave event *actually should* fire.

Update: Just tried an approach with `mouseout` instead. The same chrome bug affects this event too, so no good. :/

UPDATE: this was apparently fixed, the Chrome issue was marked "fixed", and my tests show that the current version of Chrome no longer has the issue. :D

Comment: $(window) works ?

Comment: @yjs you can switch `document` for `window`, `"body"`, `"html"`, etc. Same issues.

Comment: you want to apply mouseleave on some particular element or the complete document?

Comment: you could try to check in a mousemove listener if the mouseposition is still within the document dimensions. Don't know how it will react on fast movements tho.

Comment: @Saket - The whole document. I need to test if the mouse has left the window.

Comment: @JanWillemHuising - I actually already tried that too. The only problem is, the `mousemove` event only fires when the mouse is inside the document.

Comment: Afk right now but since relatedTarget and toElement are null, can you verify the path returned by [Event.composedPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath)? And an other solution might be to add a pointer event listener. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointerleave

Comment: @kaiido - I'm not sure what `composedPath` is, when I log it, I get `composedPath() { [native code] }` in every case. I tested the `pointerleave` event just now, unfortunately it experiences the same Chrome bug as `mouseleave`

Comment: composedPath is a function you need to console.log(evt.composedPath()) but I fear it won't work either... the :hover solution should have been the best, but if even this doesn't work this means they actually really loose the pointer, i.e it's not a problem with the mouseleave event per se, what happens is a real mouseleave, for whatever reasons...

Comment: Oh duh, `composedpath` is a function. :P sorry. Just tried it now and it looks like unfortunately it returns the same results in every case. So there may not be a safe way to detect mouse leaving the document in Chrome, without waiting to see if a mouseenter immediately follows. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, this is the solution I came up with. Hopefully someday this *major bug* in Chrome gets enough attention to get a fix.

In the event that `mouseleave` occurs as a bug, it is usually almost immediately by the `mouseenter` event. So what I did here was just wait 1/10 of a second after the mouseleave event to make sure it's not a Chrome fluke.

```
var documentMouseLeaveTimeout = null;
$(document).on("mouseleave", function() {
  documentMouseLeaveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    doSomething();
  }, 100);
});

$(document).on("mouseenter", function() {
  clearTimeout(documentMouseLeaveTimeout);
});
```

Still hoping there's a better answer.

UPDATE: this was apparently fixed, the Chrome issue was marked "fixed", and my tests show that the current version of Chrome no longer has the issue. :D